# MS Access database, update all prices in table with 10%

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I have a database with roughly 3500 products, which are all VAT included.

How would I be able to add say 10% to each of the prcies ?

**Example:**

OLD VAT PRICE: 11.90

VAT increase of 10%.

NEW VAT PRICE: 13.09

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been awhile since I've done Access, but a query like this should do the trick.

```
UPDATE tablename set VAT = VAT * 1.1;
```

This [website](http://fontstuff.com/access/acctut02.htm) should help with the specifics of entering the query into Access.

Answer (score 1):

```
update prices set price = price * 1.1
```